# what is the equivalent xml tag for specifying disk path in ehcache 3.x version

Tags: xml-configuration, ehcache-3

How to specify the disk path when the cache need to be saved in disk in ehcache 3.x version.It can be specified in ehcache 2.x version with `<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache/" />` ,but i dont find any equivalent xml tag in 3.x version.

Answer (score 4):

You have to reference "java.io.tmpdir" as a variable:

`<persistence directory="${java.io.tmpdir}/ehcache/" />`

Answer (score 2):

After a long analysis finally i found out The equivalent xml tag in 3.x is `<persistence directory="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache/" />`